# Filling a Multidimensional Array using a Stream

Tags: java, arrays, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 and currently failing to grasp Streams fully, is it possible to fill an array using the Stream functional operations? This is an example code of how I would do it with a standard for loop:

```
public static void testForLoop(){
    String[][] array = new String[3][3];
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
            array[x][y] = String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y));
        }
    }               
}

public static char letter(int i){
    return letters.charAt(i);
}
```

If it is possible how would I do it using Stream? If it is possible, is it convenient (performance and readability wise)?

Comment: Not terribly relevant, but I think you meant `array[x].length` for the inner loop.

Comment: Yes I definitely did

Comment: Just use a standard for-loop. Your code is simple and plainly obvious to the reader. As elegant as a streams solution may seem, I don't see it adds anything here.

Comment: @SaintHill Because the actual code uses a 3d array with tens to hundreds of thousands of different objects and I wanted to test if a Stream approach was faster than a standard for-loop :)

Comment: Slightly faster with a total size of the array superior to 200 (that could be processor dependent) with normal stream. Much faster with a total size superior to 1000 with parallel streams. (I'm on a QuadCore i5-3570k, 64bit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you have a solution that produces the array instead of modifying a previously defined variable:

```
String[][] array = 
    IntStream.range(0, 3)
             .mapToObj(x -> IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                     .mapToObj(y -> String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y)))
                                     .toArray(String[]::new))
             .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

If you want to use parallel streams then it's very important to avoid side effects like modifications of a variable (array or object). It might lead to race conditions or other concurrency issues. You can read more about that in [java.util.stream package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) - see *Non-interference*, *Stateless behaviors* and *Side-effects* sections.

Comment: Actually this seems a bit more convolute than the final solution I found myself, I should test which one is faster though.

Comment: Right - it's less readable than other solutions but it has the advantage that it doesn't modify an outside variable what is generally very important when you want to use parallel streams - think of race conditions.

Comment: You can read more about that in the [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package documentation (*Non-interference*, *Stateless behaviors* and *Side-effects* sections).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what I'm missing here. Isn't Arrays.setAll simply a shortcut for .mapToObj(...).toArray(...).toArray(...)?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi No, Arrays.setAll is iterating over the passed array and setting values produced by given function. Look at the source code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l4666

Comment: After some testing (benchmarks made with JMH) for the non parallel version the Arrays.setAll is slightly faster (about 5%).
The parallel version of .mapToObj is MUCH faster though (about 33%), probably due to the need of changing .forEach to .forEachOrdered

Answer (score 4):

The best way is a combination of the two approaches of [Stuart Marks’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053236/2711488).

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(
    array[x], y -> String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y))));
```

The reasoning leading to the solution is that “filling a multi-dimensional array” in Java means, “iterating over the outer array(s)” followed by “filling a one-dimensional array”  as `String[][]` is just a an array of `String[]` elements in Java. In order to set their elements you have to iterate over all `String[]` elements and since you need the index to calculate the final value, you can’t use `Arrays.stream(array).forEach(…)`. So for the outer array iterating over the indices is appropriate.

For the inner arrays the search is for the best solution for modifying an (one-dimensional) array. Here, `Arrays.setAll(…,…)` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this.

One way is with a couple nested `IntStreams` over the row and column indexes:

```
String[][] testStream() {
    String[][] array = new String[3][3];
    IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> 
        IntStream.range(0, array[x].length).forEach(y -> 
            array[x][y] = String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y))));
    return array;
}
```

Another way which seems promising is to use `Array.setAll` instead of streams. This is great for generating values for a one-dimensional array: you provide a function that maps from the array index to the value you want assigned in the array. For example, you could do this:

```
String[] sa = new String[17];
Arrays.setAll(sa, i -> letter(i));
```

Unfortunately it's less convenient for multidimensional arrays. The `setAll` method that takes a lambda that returns a value that's assigned to the array location at that index. If you've created a multidimensional array, the higher dimensions are already initialized with lower dimensional arrays. You don't want to assign to them, but you do want the implicit looping behavior of `setAll`.

With this in mind, you can use `setAll` to initialize the multidimensional array like this:

```
static String[][] testArraySetAll() {
    String[][] array = new String[3][3];
    Arrays.setAll(array, x -> {
        Arrays.setAll(array[x], y -> String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y)));
        return array[x];
    });
    return array;
}
```

The inner `setAll` is reasonably nice, but the outer one has to have a statement lambda that calls the inner `setAll` and then returns the current array. Not too pretty.

It's not clear to me that either of these approaches is any better than the typical nested for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

After working and testing around this is the best option I came with:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(array[x], y -> builder.build2Dobject(x, y)));
```

(In the specific case I proposed it would be:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(array[x], y -> String.format("%c%c", letter(x), letter(y)));
```

for a 3d array it's simply:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> IntStream.range(0, array[x].length).forEach(y -> Arrays.setAll(array[x][y], z -> builder.build3Dobject(x, y, z))));
```

this is the code that lets the program choose the fastest option:

```
public static void fill2DArray(Object[][] array, Object2DBuilderReturn builder){
    int totalLength = array.length * array[0].length;
    if (totalLength < 200){
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
                array[x][y] = builder.build2Dobject(x, y);
            }
        }
    } else if (totalLength >= 200 && totalLength < 1000){
        IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(array[x], y -> builder.build2Dobject(x, y))); 
    } else {
        IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(array[x], y -> builder.build2Dobject(x, y))); 
    }
}
```

the functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Object2DBuilderReturn<T> {
    public T build2Dobject(int a, int b);
}
```